# Fused Location Provider doesnot give Location Updates on Displacement

Tags: android, gps, android-fusedlocation

I have used Fused Location API to get location updates. I am getting updates while setting **LocationRequest** based on setTimeInterval. But I need only updates on 10m Movement. So i placed **setSmallestDisplacement(10)** .But when i put **setSmallestDisplacement(10)**, i didnt get updates. Following is my LocationUpdate class

```
public class LocationManger implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
Location mCurrentLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Context mContext;


public LocationManger(Context context) {
    super();
    mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mContext = context;
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;

}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Helper.showToast("failed", mContext);

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

if (mLocationRequest == null) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
         mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mLocationClient.connect();

}

/**
 * Function to start the location updates
 */
public void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (!mLocationClient.isConnected())
        mLocationClient.connect();
}

/**
 * function to stop the location updates
 */
public void stopUpdatingLocation() {
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {

     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, this);
    }
    mLocationClient.disconnect();

}

/**
 * function to get the current latitude
 */
public double getCurrentLatitude() {
    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
        return mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
    }
    return 0;

}

/**
 * function to get the current longitude
 */
public double getCurrentLongitude() {
    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
        return mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * function to get the current location
 */
public Location getCurrentLocation() {
    return LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
}
```

}

Please give me a solution if anyone know the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it working for time interval

Comment: Yes its working fine for time interval

Comment: try to give time interval as 0 and load it

Comment: yeah...i tried. but i dont need time interval just only need displacement

Comment: What is the GPS setting of your phone? is it High Accuracy or battery saving?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar its High Accuracy...I have set time interval 0 and displacement 10. now its working...but problem is that if device is static it makes updates with different lat n lng values

Answer (score 0):

Use setFastestInterval(0) to allow updates more frequently than called for by setInterval.  Otherwise you will miss some updates from displacement

Comment: Does it work without time interval. I dont need updates based on time interval